# Difference between .value and .setValue in reactive forms in Angular 7+

Tags: angular

I would like to fully understand what are the differences between .value and .setValue in angular 7+ and under which circumstances that are suitable for using .value or .setValue?

Example 1: `this.createLocForm.setValue(data);`

Example 2:  `this.data = this.createLocForm.value`

Comment: They both are completely different: `this.createLocForm.value` used to get the value of the form group and `setValue` used to set the value for formGroup!

Comment: thank you @PrashantPimpale. For the syntax setValue, is it also apply for subscribe too? Example:  `.subscribe(data =>  this.createLocForm.setValue(data);)`

[edited] does it have the same meaning that the "data" will contain the values then .setValue() will set the values of "data" to the Form?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Example 1: this.createLocForm.setValue(data);

> Use the setValue() method to set a new value for individual control. The setValue() method strictly adheres to the structure of the form group and replaces the entire value for the control. Please read this for [more details](https://medium.com/@samichkhachkhi/setvalue-vs-patchvalue-angular-a64a55e912b8)

### Example 2: this.data = this.createLocForm.value

> *This is a read-only property*. You can't assign any value for this property. You can only do read the control values by using this property.

Answer (score 2):

They both are completely different:

### [`.setValue()`](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#setvalue) is a function which used to:

> `Sets the value of the FormGroup. It accepts an object that matches the structure of the group, with control names as keys.`

For example:

If you have:

```
const formGroup = new FormGroup({
  name: new FormControl(),
  mobileNo: new FormControl()
});
```

then your setValue:

```
formGroup.setValue({name: 'Prashant', mobileNo: '99XXXXXXXX'});
```

**In case of the below code, it will not work:**

```
formGroup.setValue({full_name: 'Prashant', mobileNumber: '99XXXXXXXX'}); -- The keys are important for set value
```

or

```
formGroup.setValue({ name: 'Prashant'}); -- Will not work as it is missing mobileNo key from the specified object
```

---

### [`.value`](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#value) is a property:

> which used to get/access the value of formGroup.

Comment: I am very appreciated !!! It is very details. I understood the differences between them

Comment: are they placeholder values?

Comment: @Rahul unable to understand your comment

Comment: @PrashantPimpale I am a beginner, I was asking where do we use setvalue and patchvalue? What's the purpose?

Comment: @Rahul purpose is to set pre-selected values in the form..for example in case of update data we need to show existing data to end user

Answer (score 2):

setValue() will set the value of all form controls of the form group.

patchValue() method will also set Formcontrol values from a model but only for those which we have mentioned in the model. So,  it is not necessary to pass all the model info in patchValue() method.